# Expected value for this strategy of choosing a number between 0 and 1, twice?

Tags: probability

I choose a number between 0 and 1. If I am not satisfied with this number, I can choose again. I choose the strategy to maximize my outcome (bigger number). What's my expected outcome?

It's easy if it's a discrete problem, but since it's continuous I'm not really sure how to calculate the expected value.

Comment: Presumably by "pick a number between 0 and 1" you mean "pick a random number between 0 and 1." And by satisfied, you mean you want a large number? That is, a strategy to get the largest number?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose I picked the number $0.75$.  Should I discard this and pick again?  Why not?

Suppose I picked the number $0.25$.  Should I discard this and pick again?  Why?

Suppose I picked a number $x$.  If I were to pick again, how much would I stand to gain or lose on average in terms of $x$ for doing so.  What then is the rule I should follow to maximize my value at the end of the game?

> If you picked a number greater than or equal to $0.5$, keep the number, otherwise discard it and pick again.  Having picked a number $x$, you would stand to gain $0.5-x$, which is positive if and only if $x<0.5$.

$~$

In calculating the expected value of the final result, how often do we choose not to draw again and what is the expected number of the result that we would have ended with?  How often do we choose to draw again and what is the expected number of the result that we would have ended with?

Comment: So the probability of choosing again is 1/2. The expected value after choosing again is 0.5. Are you saying then the expected value is 1/2(0.5+0.5) = 0.5?

Comment: The expected value *after* choosing again will be $0.5$.  What is the expected value *given that your first number was high enough that you chose not to choose again*?  It won't be $0.5$.  Every possible number I end up with would be between $0.5$ and $1$... so...

Comment: Oh right, then is it 1/2*(0.75 + 0.5)? Given that if I keep the first number, the expected number i would've got would be 0.75. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is my interpretation.  Now, all that remains is formalizing the proof that the proposed strategy is indeed optimal, but it should follow quickly from the observations made above.  We get that this strategy yields an expected value of $\frac{5}{8}$

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but I am confused about something. Since the original expectation was 0.5, shouldn't the new expectation be closer to 0.5 than 1?

Comment: It is...  0.625 is closer to 0.5 than 1

Comment: No I mean the expected value 0.75. Shouldn't this expected value be closer to  0.5?

Comment: No... the expected value of uniformly selected random number from the range 0 to 1 given that we know it is bigger than 0.5 is the same as the expected value of a number picked from the range 0.5 to 1.  That being the middle of the range,  i.e. 0.75